# boundary of zero level set (free boundary) of a p-harmonic function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, regularity-theory-of-pdes

let $u$ be a p-harmonic function in $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^N$.

that is $-div(|\nabla u|^{p-2}\nabla u)=-\Delta_p u=0$ in $\Omega$.

We already know that the set $\{u=0\}$ is locally a $C^{1,\alpha}$ hypersurface at the points where $\nabla u\neq 0$.

What can be said about the overall regularity of the set $\partial \{u\neq 0\}$.
this will also include the points where gradient of u is zero.

Comment: what does p-harmonic mean?

Comment: @zhw. i edited my question. please see.